# Python - executable file (compatibility)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I make python program (with Tkinter) in ubuntu 10.04 lts and I generated executable file with pyinstaller. How can I check, which operating systems are compatible with my program? Or does my program run on every Linux? Thank you.